# Way to have browsers ignore a specific string of characters in middle of a URL?

Tags: regex, http, variables, url

I have a very narrow, specific case where an application takes a URL and appends the name of a specific server to the end of it from a variable passed to it, but it does it as `host:servername001`.  The problem is that the URL doesn't work if `host:` is there.  Is there a string I can add to the URL prior to the variable that will tell it to ignore the next 5 characters (eg, the `host:`) and then use the resulting URL?

The URL it would pass is like:

`https://website1/path/server.do?sysparm_query=name=$host.name`

Which results in an actual URL output of:

`https://website1/path/server.do?sysparm_query=name=host:servername001`

I am looking for a way that I can have it ignore the 5 characters (host:) before the servername.  I can control the URL string, but not the $host.name variable.

Thoughts or suggestions?

EDIT for clarification:

I'm passing a URL and a variable to an output. This is all in a 3rd party app that I don't have a lot of control over. I can edit the URL. Right now, it's:

`https://website1/path/server.do?sysparm_query=name=`

I need to append the servername from the variable at the end of that URL.  The only one I can use for that is

`$host.name`

Which adds "host:" right before the server name in the resulting URL.  I need to know if there is something I can add to the URL string above, that would tell a browser to ignore "the next 5 characters" so the result is just that the URL looks like this:

`https://website1/path/server.do?sysparm_query=name=servername001`

Instead of like this:

`https://website1/path/server.do?sysparm_query=name=host:servername001`

Hope that makes sense...

Comment: I am not clear what the input is. Is `$host.name` the variable you want to fix? E.g. this string? `"https://website1/path/server.do?sysparm_query=name=" + $host.name`

Comment: If so, you can remove the host as follows: `$host.name.replace(/^[^:]*:/, '')`

Comment: Added info to my original question to clarify.  Essentially, I need to know if there is something I can add to a URL string that would tell a browser to ignore "the next 5 characters" so the result is just that the URL looks like this:

`https://website1/path/server.do?sysparm_query=name=servername001`

Instead of like this:

`https://website1/path/server.do?sysparm_query=name=host:servername001`

Hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snipped to append the host name without the `host:` prefix:

```js
var url = "https://website1/path/server.do?sysparm_query=name="; 
var $host = {
  name: 'host:servername001'
};
var newUrl = url + $host.name.replace(/^[^:]*:/, '');
console.log('- url:    ' + url);
console.log('- newUrl: ' + newUrl);
```